# Trouble Re-order a HTML table when the user clicks on the table header

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to re-order a HTML table when the user clicks on the table header. Here is all I can do, but still doesn't work.
  i want to do sorting  By default it will come as **event_date desc**.
[image]

it works properly

Now when i click on event name then its should do  sorting as **event_name desc** and when i again click on event name then its should be **event_name asc**.

How to do this?
please help me as soon as possible...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This can be done using ajax call, when user clicks on `event_name` send a `ajax` request to a function which will order the result by asc/dsc, use a param `sort` which will tell in which order to sort the results, on success update the results div with sorted results.

Comment: `as soon as possible.` . Yes sir

Comment: is there any jquery for sorting?@saveATcode if yes please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

you could use
[jQgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

It is much easier to manage tables using jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it using javascript then its better to use any external js like datatable.

Or if are using php you can append parameter (asc/desc) to `Event Title` link and according to that sort the result.

Plz show wht you have done to find appropriate solution.